# MySQL 5.5.16 allows anonymous connections

Tags: mysql, database-administration, mysql5

Apparently, I can connect to MySQL (at least from my localhost) without having to provide any username or password. I can even put anything as username, as long as the password is empty. I have access to the `information_schema` and `test` databases. I can create tables. If I run `SELECT USER()` it returns the proper value randomstring@localhost, where the random string is whatever I used for username when I connected.

The `mysql.user` table contains root@localhost, root@127.0.0.1, @localhost and pma@localhost. I manually set encrypted passwords to all the records (`UPDATE user SET password=...`) and only root has any privileges, the other two records have "N" for all privileges. That record with the empty username looks suspicious, but I don't think it has anything to do with this and I think it was there from the beginning.

To make matters worse, if I add a user with a password, I can only connect using empty string as password (just like if I put anything as username). If I try to connect using the username I created and password I supplied when creating it (`CREATE USER .. IDENTIFIED BY ..`) it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how I can fix this?

**Note:** I am using MySQL 5.5.16 for Windows, provided by the XAMPP package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to simply remove the anonymous user.

In the future, running /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation (Location in RPM Installation) will prompt you to remove these anonymous users.

> By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone
> to log into MySQL without having to have a user account created for
> them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation
> go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving into a
> production environment.
>
> Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
> ... Success!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the user entry with the empty username.  It is the cause.  Use `select user();` when logged in to verify that it's the user that you logged in as.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html):

> Some accounts are for anonymous users. These have an empty user name. The anonymous accounts have no password, so anyone can use them to connect to the MySQL server.