# MySQL allows entry without Password

Tags: linux, mysql, security, bug

I have configured my MySQL Database to require passwords on all users, even root from the machine itself.

Now I discovered that there are empty Users in my Database

Reproduce: `mysql -u root -p` and then `use mysql;` & `select * from user;`

It gives me 2 entries, one with "localhost" and user <empty> and one with the machine's hostname and <empty>.

Now I tried to access the account with `mysql -u ' '` (yes it's correct, leave a space between the ' things)
and I log in without a password.
The user can "only" see information_schema and test, the two databases created by default.
He does not has access to mysql or any other custom created databases.

I already changed the Password of this user to something I won't tell you

```
mysql -u root -p
use mysql;
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('thisisasecretpassword') WHERE USER='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now my Questions:

- **Is any MySQL Server vulnerable for an attack with this entry?**
- **Could an attacker break out of this account or the two default databases?**
- **Should I password-protect those Users or can I delete them? Are They required for some MySQL-internal things?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are anonymous users and, as such, don't need passwords. They are created by default on all installations. I'm not sure why it's done this way.

You can either set a password for them or remove them. From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html:

> If you want to prevent clients from connecting as anonymous users without a password, you should either assign a password to each anonymous account or else remove the accounts.

Seems to be a duplicate of this one: [MySQL 5.5.16 allows anonymous connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/368641/mysql-5-5-16-allows-anonymous-connections)

Comment: Thank you for the Link, didn't find it myself ;)
By the way, are there more things like that (which I need to take care of) for MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_secure_installation` to remove anonymous users, test databases and also prevent remote connect using `root` user.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-secure-installation.html